# Base Activity Button Click's not working in child activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am new to android. In my app, having common header.

I have created common header.xml and include that header.xml in all the activites.

But the button clicks [listener] not working.

How to solve the issue. this is the code.

### Header.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutHeader"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:text="Home" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:text="Accounts" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:text="History" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

### Home.xml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

   <include
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       layout="@layout/header" />

     <EditText
      android:id="@+id/txtOTPCode"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="textPersonName" />


     <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnVerify"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="verify" />

     </LinearLayout>
```

### BaseHeaderActivity.java

```
  import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;

  public abstract class BaseHeaderActivity extends Activity 
  {
Button btn1, btn2, btn3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.header);

    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Programming stuf
            //show the another view
            System.out.println("Home button Action");
        }
    });
}
```

}

### Home Activity.java

```
      import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeActivity extends BaseHeaderActivity
{
Button btnVerify;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    btnVerify = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVerify);
}
}
```

base activities button clicks not working..!
Kindly suggest the solution.

Thanks in advance,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create two different activities for this. Create one activity and use all buttons (including button in header.xml) similarly

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 Button btn1,btnVerify;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Programming stuf
            //show the another view
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Home button Action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btnVerify = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVerify);
    btnVerify.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Programming stuf
            //show the another view
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Verify Action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
  }
 }
```

You can not use one layout xml file with single activity only.

Note - If you still want to create two different activities - one base and one child then you need to use setContentView() method in base activity with main layout file (Home.xml in your case) and extend it with child activity. Remember in this case dont use setContentView() method in Child Activity. This scenario is not preferred generally unless we want to create several child of same activity.